Why are internal resources accessed via NPM arriving from my public IP address?
Situation: I have a domain, let's say mydomain.com.
On a server in my local network, I have a few services running, including Nginx Proxy Manager.
In NPM, I have configured various hosts such as service1.mydomain.com, service2.mydomain.com, and so on.
All of these services are publicly accessible. So I can reach service1.mydomain.com from both inside and outside of my network.
On my own DNS server, I have created an A record for *.mydomain.com pointing to NGINX, so that I can reach all of my services from within my own network using their FQDN.
One of the services, let's say service3.mydomain.com is a bit more sensitive. So I've placed an Access List called "LAN Only" which only allows RFC1918 addresses.
And here's where it breaks down: When this Access List is active on service3.mydomain.com, I get a 403 forbidden even when accessing the resource from within my own network.
Looking at the NPM access log:
[error] 10010#10010: *2988 access forbidden by rule, client: {MY PUBLIC IP}, server: service3.mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "service3.mydomain.com", referrer: "https://{PRIVATE IP}:{PORT}/"

So I am accessing internal resources, from within the LAN, from my public IP addresses. Why is that?
It's not a DNS issue, considering dig service3.mydomain.com gives the correct local A record with the private IP and I can ping it just fine.
Maybe good to know: If I unplug the cable from my ISP, I can still reach all my services perfectly fine. And the ones with the "LAN ONLY" ACL now work, as the logs confirm I am accessing them from my private client IP. My browser does not use DNS over TLS or HTTPS, it just uses the host DNS resolvers.

Nginx Proxy Manager  is doing its best to be sure that the source address is preserved, even through an IPv4 NAT.
Read the config files. Assuming I found a representative nginx.conf  it has set_real_ip_from   for essentially all of RFC 1918. Inside nginx you are no longer working with the internal address.
An entirely internal service would not need to go through the proxy at the internet edge.  You could choose to not proxy it and have service3 resolve to the backend host.  Or, proxy it but alter the config to have a network that is not in the real IP ranges.
